# Creating a SMTP Service using HTML code

Tags: html, smtp

I want this code to send mails, right now when i click it it doesn't do anything,I've figured out i need to setup a SMTP server, i just can't quite do it, help me, please.

**To be more clear, what i want is, to a customer of my company going into my website to fill up the form and click sent and by doing this, a mail with the form details goes to the company email so we can then help the customer with his needs.**

I would add images of the form, but i'm not allowed yet, sorry!

The code of the entire form is:

```
div class="row row-centered">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-lg-6 col-centered">
    <div class="panel panel-default accountContainer">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <form id="Form">
                <div class="row" ng-if="!settings.UserInfo.isAuthenticated">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label><h4><b>Nome:</h4></b></label>

                            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label><h4><b>Endereço de e-mail:</h4></b></label>

                            <input type="text" name="mail" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label><h4><b>Titulo (Assunto):</h4></b></label>

                            <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                        <div class="form-group" style="margin-top:10px;">
                            <label><h4><b>Categoria do Problema:</b></h4></label>

                            <select placeholder="Select a Type" name="TicketType" class="form-control">
                                <option value="enabled">Selecione aqui...</option>
                                <option>Hardware</option>
                                <option>Software</option>
                                <option>Fazer Encomenda</option>
                                <option>Problemas com a encomenda</option>
                                <option>Entrega de encomenda</option>
                                <option>Devoluções</option>
                                <option>RMA</option>
                                <option>Outros</option>

                            </select>
                            <div class="help-block">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="form-group" style="margin-top:10px;">
                            <label><h4><b>Descrição do Problema/Encomenda:<h4></b></label>

                            <textarea placeholder="Escreva aqui..." cols="70" rows="8" maxlength="500"></textarea>
                            <br><br>
                                <form action="mailto:maildaempresa@qualquercoisa.com" method="GET">
                                    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" style="background-color: orange">
                                </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: The problem is that your `<form>` element `method` is `GET`, when you want `POST` in order to send the data. Also, your `<form>` will need `<input>` or `<textarea>` values inside of it (other than the submission) for the user to enter their information. Each of these will also need a `name` attribute.

Comment: Thanks for your help Obsidian, how can i accomplish that, sorry i'm still learning!